# How to save "mtr --report-wide" output to textfile?

Tags: linux, debian, nohup, traceroute

I am having troubles saving the output of "mtr --report-wide" to a textfile. Probably due to the different way both options output their information. I know i could use the "--raw" argument but i would like to avoid that.

Does anybody have a solution?

Linux version:

```
Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Works:

```
"nohup mtr --report destination --report-cycles=10 > output &"
```

Does not work(process never stops):

```
"nohup mtr --report-wide destination --report-cycles=10 > output &"
```

Answer (score 0):

> process never stops

Quite the contrary - the process is stopped immediately due to a `SIGTTOU` signal, and thus never terminates.

> solution?

Just redirect `STDERR` also by using `… >&output&` instead of `… >output&`.